# What are `git diff --word-diff' default regexps?

Tags: git, git-diff, word-diff

`git diff` has option `--word-diff-regex=<...>` that matches words. There are special default values for some languages (as said in `man 5 gitattributes`). But what are these? No description in docs, I looked up sources of `git`, haven't found them too.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm on `git 1.9.1`, but I'll accept answers for any version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sources contain the default word regexes in the [`userdiff.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7f4ba4b6e3ba7075ca6b379ba23fd3088cbe69a8/userdiff.c) file. The `PATTERNS` and `IPATTERN` macros take the base word regex as their third parameter, and add `"|[^[:space:]]|[\xc0-\xff][\x80-\xbf]+"` to make sure all non-whitespace characters that aren't part of a larger word are treated as a word by themselves, and assuming UTF-8, without splitting up multi-byte characters. For example, in:

> ```
> PATTERNS("tex", "^(\\\\((sub)*section|chapter|part)\\*{0,1}\\{.*)$",
>          "\\\\[a-zA-Z@]+|\\\\.|[a-zA-Z0-9\x80-\xff]+"),
> ```

the word regex is `"\\\\[a-zA-Z@]+|\\\\.|[a-zA-Z0-9\x80-\xff]+|[^[:space:]]|[\xc0-\xff][\x80-\xbf]+"`.

In this case, the `|[\xc0-\xff][\x80-\xbf]+` happens not to have any benefit, as everything covered by `[\xc0-\xff][\x80-\xbf]+` is already covered by `[a-zA-Z0-9\x80-\xff]+`, but it doesn't cause any harm either.

Comment: on git version 2.8.3, $ git diff --word-diff-regex="\\\\[a-zA-Z@]+|\\\\.|[a-zA-Z0-9\x80-\xff]+|[^[:space:]]|[\xc0-\xff][\x80-\xbf]+"  and git diff --word-diff produce similar, but different results

Answer (score 2):

A list of predefined diff drivers (they all have predefined word diff regexes) is given in the [docs for `.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_hunk_header). It is further stated that

> you still need to enable this with the attribute mechanism, via .gitattributes

So to activate the `tex` pattern shown in hvd's answer for all `*.tex` files, you could issue the following command in your project root (omit the quotes under Windows):

```
echo '*.tex diff=tex' >> .gitattributes
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: Regarding those patterns, Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), is clearer and reminds developers that the `userdiff` patterns should be kept simple and permissive, assuming that the contents they apply are always syntactically correct.

See [commit b6029b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6029b3279ef5997796de99ce9319a5f1499df21) (10 Aug 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e1eb133](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e1eb13347610bd5b062377f2e8d7f807c6e89d07), 30 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`userdiff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6029b3279ef5997796de99ce9319a5f1499df21): comment on the builtin patterns

> Remind developers that they do not need to go overboard to implement patterns to prepare for invalid constructs.
> They only have to be sufficiently permissive, assuming that the payload is syntactically correct, and that may allow them to be simpler.
>
> Text stolen mostly from, and further improved by, Johannes Sixt.

So those built-in patterns now have as a comment:

```c
/*
 * Built-in drivers for various languages, sorted by their names
 * (except that the "default" is left at the end).
 *
 * When writing or updating patterns, assume that the contents these
 * patterns are applied to are syntactically correct.  The patterns
 * can be simple without implementing all syntactical corner cases, as
 * long as they are sufficiently permissive.
 */
static struct userdiff_driver builtin_drivers[] = {
```